# Cant make WAMP available to public

Tags: apache, wamp, port

I've been searching for 2 days now and I still can't make it work

Things I did:

- Forward port 80.  Checking the port 80 at http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ . SAYS ITS OPEN
- modified my httpd.conf and I added the line "Allow from all"
- clicked "put online" button

  ---

  - entering Localhost lets me access
  - entering my local IP with :80 at the end, lets me access
  - Entering my public ip, does NOT let me access.

I have no idea what to do now..

Comment: Don't panic, as you apparently currently do. Get systematic instead of trying around. 1. is your "public ip address" really correct (_really_)? 2. forwarded port 80 _from where to where_? 3. make a `telnet` test to port 80 on your public ip address, what is the result? 4. what is the _exact_ error message you get when trying to access? 5. check the log files of the http server.

Comment: Hello. i get my public ip from searching "what is my IP" on google. 
Telnet testing gives me "could not open connection to the host. Connect failed. Also entering my public Ip on Chrome gives me timed-out message "Oops chrome was unable..etc etc "

Comment: How is your system ("localhost") connected to the Internet? Some sort of router? If so, have you configured forward of port 80 from the router to the system? Oh, and for testing, do you have another computer or smartphone at hand in your local network?

Comment: i Did forward the port 80 from the router. i test it and it says its open..Also i can access my local ip from the other computers i have in the house

Comment: No idea how you tested if the port forwarding works, if you cannot connect, but anyway: if it does, then that would leave a firewall on your system. That is why I asked for another network enabled device inside your network.

Comment: I said i test the port from this website http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what that site does. If telnet can't connect, then the port is closed. Period.

Comment: It really would help if you have some other network enabled device in your local network. You could then decide if you have a problem on your system or on the router.

Answer (score 1):

Most home routers dont have the feature required to `loopback` to your external ip addres from inside your local network.

Test your external access from next door or a friends house. You have to be physically external to your network.